# Mounting volume/partition with permissions for user

Tags: permissions, mount

A volume intended for use by my user was created at OS installation with root ownership and my user lacks write permissions.

Some solutions I've read about include:

- changing ownership of the mount point with `chown`
- adding group write permissions with `chmod`
- adding `user` or `users` mount option in `/etc/fstab`.

What is the best practice for this situation, and what are the implications of each approach?

Comment: Love it when your **exact** question has been asked (and answered)!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it's in `/etc/fstab`, then it will mount at boot. 
As only `root` has write permissions,
you'll need to modify it so that the user has those permissions. 
The best way is:

```
chown -R user /mnt/point
```

where *`user`* represents your user name (or user ID),
and, obviously, `/mnt/point` represents the mount point of your file system. 
If the `root` group has write permission as well and you want another group to have it then you can use:

```
chown -R user:group /mnt/point
```

If the `root` group doesn't have write access, then you can use `chmod` next:

```
chmod -R 775 /mnt/point
```

That will give write permission to the group if it's not there and read and execute to everyone else. You can modify the `775` to give whatever permissions you want to everyone else as that will be specified by the third number.

To better cover what you asked in your comment below:

You can add the `user` option to `/etc/fstab`, but that only allows the file system to be mounted by any user. It won't change the permissions on the file system,
which is why you need `chown` and/or `chmod`. You can go ahead and add the `user` option so that a regular user without `sudo` can mount it should it be unmounted.

For practicality, the best option here is `chown` as it gives the user the needed permissions instantly. The `chmod` command can be used afterwards if the permissions need to be modified for others.

Comment: The `chown` approach works, but requires authentication to mount (if unmounted after boot). I presume adding `user` or `users` to the `fstab` mount options would allow user mounting without authentication? What are the practicality and security considerations of each approach?

Comment: @adatum See my update.

Comment: Do you have to run `chown` *after* mounting the partition? My mount point began as owned by a non-root because I logged in as e.g. bobby and created /home/bobby/mnt/usb. `ls -l` confirmed bobby's ownership. But, after mounting, `ls -l` gave root for owner and group. I then had to 'chown -R bobby ~/mnt/usb' as mounted; only then did bobby get write permission. Is this the expected outcome or peculiar to my system (OpenWrt)? I believe it would improve the answer to specify whether in general the `chown` method is expected to work on a mount point as yet unmounted.

Comment: chown/chmod can be used to let me do one thing, one time, that I need to do to a file/drive that never had any business being owned by root in the first place, but it has to be redone constantly, as the effects are not persistent. How do I set up a drive that is mounted at boot-up, such that the entire drive (including all contents) stays owned by the primary user, and permissioned to all users, even after I do things like rebooting, or writing to it from a program running as root?

Answer (score 3):

I was doing `chown -R user /mnt/point` but it was not working. It turned out that I first need to umount and then set the permission

```
umount /mnt/point
chown -R user /mnt/point
```

Now mount or restart (if you have the /etc/fstab entry).

Answer (score 0):

If mountpoint owner is still root, then it worked to set `mode=0755,uid=1000` in 4th column of the fstab. uid is the number returned by `id` command. I am unsure if it would work to use the username directly instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

For a pendrive, a possibility is to add a label with gparted; after that, when you plug the usb, it will be in `/media/username/label_added`.

If you use `sudo mount /dev/sdxx /media/username/destination`, even if you own that destination, permissions will change to `root`