# Why must I provide authentication to mount SATA HDDs? Why are they in read-only mode?

Tags: permissions, hard-disk, authentication, external-hdd, sata

I am running Fedora 36, and have two or three HDDs connected via SATA (including the drive that Fedora on). When I attempt to access the drives in the file manager for the first time since power-on, the system prompts me for my password. Why? They are not encrypted as far as I know. Also, even after mounting, the drives are throwing read-only permissions errors, even with root privileges. Why? How can I write to them? Windows and Neon do not have this problem. Am using Plasma.

Here is the associated `mount` line: `/dev/sda2 on /mnt/64704E01704DDB06 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)`

Here is the journalctl -r info (I filtered, so I may have cut out something important).

```
[wilbur@fedora ~]$ journalctl -r | grep sda
Apr 21 11:07:08 fedora ntfs-3g[921]: Mount options: nosuid,nodev,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,ro,fsname=/dev/sda2,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 21 11:07:08 fedora ntfs-3g[921]: Mounted /dev/sda2 (Read-Only, label "JRHDD1", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel:  sda: sda2
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Apr 21 07:06:50 fedora kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
```

Answer (score 2):

> the system prompts me for my password. Why? They are not encrypted as far as I know

The system ask for the administrator password (which will most likely be your password) because mounting is a privileged operation. There are some exceptions, for example for removable devices (USB flash drives), but for internal drives, system will ask you for passphrase. If you want to avoid this, you can add the drives to [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab) with the `user` or `users` option. (You can also use GNOME Disks to configure (auto)mounting.)

> the drives are throwing read-only permissions errors

If this is a linux filesystem, then you need to [set correct permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454962/mounting-volume-partition-with-permissions-for-user) on it to make it writable by your user. If it is a Windows filesystem, you need to set correct [mount options for it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511872/what-is-the-correct-permission-in-etc-fstab-to-mount-ntfs), but that should be covered by UDisks which does the mounting.

Comment: I somewhat discovered the first half in gdisk, and now they mount automatically. Pasting is still forbidden, though. I guess UDisks didn't cover it? Edit: Hang on, it's working now. Back on Windows 11, I gave all users of the PC "full control" over the drive, so I guess it's fixed now. TYJ, and thank you!

Comment: Strike that, it's failing again. I can't paste. Seems kind of erratic as to when this has happened.

Comment: Sounds like your device might be getting mounted as ready only because of errors. Check output of `mount` do you see `rw` or `ro` option for your disk? Also check logs (`journalctl -r`) for errors.

Comment: /dev/sda2 on /mnt/64704E01704DDB06 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)

Comment: journalctl -r | grep sda doesn't appear to show any errors, and ...grep "sda|err" returns nothing. It does however show that the drive is mounting as read-only.

Comment: Nothing has given me write permissions. Help!

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I see ro on both.